# using new within the define module requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have been defining my controllers like this for a while(without any lib) but the dependencies drove me crazy and now I'm trying to integrate requireJs.

```
controller = new function () {

    this.test = "Hello World";

    this.__construct = function () {
       alert(this.test);
    };

    this.__construct();

};
```

How can one transform this to a requireJs Module? I have tried the following

```
define(function () {

   return controller = new function () {

       this.test = "Hello World";

       this.__construct = function () {
           alert(this.test);
       };

       this.__construct();
    };

});
```

Could I simply do ?

```
define(controller);
```

In My Main

```
//main.js
requirejs(['controller']);
```

However, the alert popup wont show up.

Answer (score 1):

Your `controller` definition should be okay - however, you're misusing require in your `main.js`:

```
//main.js
requirejs(['controller'], function(controller){
    // use controller here
});
```